# Groupping List into sub lists with bool in c#

Tags: c#

My question is, i can group consecutive numbers in a List with below closed function but i can't get it   worked with bool extension.

static bool works fine and detects consecutive numbers as per below pattern but it doesn't group it.

Do you think why and/or how can i group it as per below bool extension??

this is list (10, 10, 2, 1, 0, 5, 6, 7, 8, 4, 0, 11, 12, 0, 2)

And the outcome should be;

group: (10)
group: (10)
group: (2,1,0)
group: (5,6,7,8)
group: (4)
group: (0)
group: (11,12,0)
group: (2)

Any ideas/help pls??

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var groups = new List<int> { 10, 10, 2, 1, 0, 5, 6, 7, 8, 4, 0, 11, 12, 0, 2 };
            var cons = groups.ConsecutiveNumbers();
            var result = groups.GroupConsecutive(cons);

            foreach (var g in result)
            {
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("group: {0}", string.Join(",", g.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToList()));
                    Console.ReadLine();

                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static class ConsExample
    {

        public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> GroupConsecutive(this IEnumerable<int> list, bool pred)
        {
            var groupCons = new List<int>();

            //When i try below code it works and groups consecutive numbers
            /*
             foreach (var i in list)
            {
                if (groupAscending.Count() == 0 || i - groupAscending[groupAscending.Count - 1] == 1)
                {
                    groupAscending.Add(i);
                }

                else
                {
                    yield return groupCons;
                    groupCons = new List<int> { i };
                }
            */

            //if i try below code it doesn't group it..why??
            foreach (var i in list)
            {

                if (pred)
                {
                    groupCons.Add(i);
                }

                else
                {
                    yield return groupCons;
                    groupCons = new List<int> { i };
                }
            }
            yield return groupCons;
        }

        public static bool ConsecutiveNumbers(this List<int> consNumbers)
        {
            if (consNumbers.Count < 3)
            {
                return false;
            }

            int[] pattern = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 0 };
            int[] revPattern = pattern.Reverse().ToArray(); ;
            bool t = true;

            for (int i = 0; i < pattern.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < consNumbers.Count; j++)
                {
                    if (consNumbers[j] == pattern[(i + j > pattern.Length - 1 ? pattern.Length - 1 : i + j)])
                    {
                        t = true;
                        continue;
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        t = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (t) break;
            }

            if (t == true)
            {
                return true;
            }

            t = true;

            for (int i = 0; i < revPattern.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < consNumbers.Count; j++)
                {

                    if (consNumbers[j] == revPattern[(i + j > revPattern.Length - 1 ? revPattern.Length - 1 : i + j)])
                    {
                        t = true;
                        continue;
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        t = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (t) break;
            }

            if (t == true)
            {
                return true;
            }

            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you treat `11,12, 0` as consecutive numbers?

Comment: what's the result of `5,4,3,4,5`

Comment: @Peter Csala, it's for the rule of game, value of element should act 0 or 13.

Comment: @fubo, nope that shouldn't be like that, 5,4,3 should be groupped and 4,5 should be groupped seperately.

Comment: I would guess the problem is that `ConsecutiveNumbers` only return a single bool that is used as input to the next function. So `GroupConsecutive` will either add all the numbers to one single list, or all numbers to one list each. I would guess you wanted `GroupConsecutive` to take a `list<bool>` as input

Comment: @JonasH, can you pls explain how i can use list<bool> to implement?

Comment: @Catklysm Did the below solution work for you?

Comment: @mjwills, thank you very much it basically works for what asked, i was just trying to understand the code. Coz i should add more functions like to group same numbers if their count greater than 2 and how can be added a joker value.. I mean if a joker value without value (only has a bool joker) comes from 1,2 like(1,2,J) that should be grouped as well. If i could do it like my question, i can implement joker, but with your way i need to figure out that also.

Comment: Yeah you'll need to tweak it to handle any new requirements - but hopefully you get the general idea. Basically set `directionAscending = null;
                    currentKey++;` every time you want to start a new group.

Comment: @mjwills, thanks i tried but things getting crazy :) can you help me about my last edit?

Comment: @mjwills, also this groups 11,12,0,1,2 etc which it shouldn't be, so we are back to beginning.

Comment: @mjwills, actually in orginal question "bool" extension does that, thats why i try to combine the codes wihch i asked. I get the mark back because i am still waiting other opinions about my original question. Anyhow execuse me if i disturbed you.

Answer (score 0):

`GroupBy` can be helpful with solving these kinds of problems.

> 10 10 2,1,0 5,6,7,8 4 0 11,12,0 2

Basically you switch the key whenever an entry is not 1 more or 1 less than the previous entry (with some additional logic to detect direction changing and rolling over from 12 to 0).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp4
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var groups = new List<int> { 10, 10, 2, 1, 0, 5, 6, 7, 8, 4, 0, 11, 12, 0, 2 };

            int? previousValue = null;
            int currentKey = 0;
            bool? directionAscending = null;

            var bob = groups.GroupBy((j) =>
            {
                var oneLessValue = (previousValue - 1) % 13;
                var oneMoreValue = (previousValue + 1) % 13;

                if (previousValue != null && ((j == oneLessValue) || (j == oneMoreValue)))
                {
                    if (directionAscending == null)
                    {
                        directionAscending = (j == previousValue - 1);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var newDirectionAscending = (j == previousValue - 1);

                        if (newDirectionAscending != directionAscending)
                        {
                            directionAscending = null;
                            currentKey++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    directionAscending = null;
                    currentKey++;
                }

                previousValue = j;
                return currentKey;
            }).Select(z => z.ToList()).ToList();

            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, bob.Select(z => string.Join(",", z))));
        }
    }
}
```